# Windows Script Host Error - Running Appium from CMD

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, appium, jscript

I'm trying to run Appium from command line but getting error 800A138F - Microsoft JScript runtime error.

I have created a BATCH file containing the following data.

```js
ECHO
START "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\node_modules\appium\lib\server\main.js" --address 127.0.0.1 --port 4723 --platform-name Android --platform-version 23 --automation-name Appium --log-no-color
```

Then, the windows script host pop up error appears.
[image]

Comment: May i know which OS you are using. Is node is installed properly . This is something related to OS what i feel. Take a look of http://www.solvusoft.com/en/errors/runtime-errors/mozilla-foundation/javascript/800a138f-javascript-error-800a138f/

Comment: Can you post logs/screenshot ?

Comment: Windows 7 OS. I'll be right upload a scrrenshot

Comment: @workspace node is installed properly since Appium works good from gui